# 2006 macbook give me flashing folder with question mark without disk

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, leopard

I am currently using a early 2006 macbook running on os x 10.5 and I am facing the flashing folder when turning it on. I have tried holding command & c and etc but nothing happens when I hold option after hearing the chime the arrow come up and i don't see no folder but it stays like this. I do not own any disks to put into my macbook because it was given to me. i do not want to take it to the shop because it will cost more than the laptop it self will cost. Is there any type of way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need a disk to boot off and given what is happening a new hard disk as well

Comment: Can you say more clearly what the main issue is?  What initial steps might help you most?

Answer (score 1):

The folder with question mark on start up means that the Mac is unable to locate your boot drive.

[image: OS X boot with question mark]

Many possible causes:

1. Corrupted boot disk.

   - You can try Disk Utility using a boot via external unit (CD-ROM, external HDD, USB) to repair the disk. If you are unable to see the primary disk via Disk Utility follow the two possibility below.
2. HDD broken.

   - Replace your HDD and install a fresh copy of OS X or try to extract your data form the broken HDD and move it to the new one.
3. HDD SATA cable disconnected / broken.

   - Your HDD is connected via SATA flat cable. Open your Mac, check this cable if it is disconnected or try to replace it.